# looping a lineinfile task with duplicates

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to add some lines to the `.bashrc` file

```yaml
      - name: "Test..."
        ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
          dest: /home/toto/.bashrc
          line: "{{ item }}"
        loop:
          - echo
          - screenfetch
          - echo
```

But the third line is 'skipped'.

```
changed: [192.168.0.250] => (item=echo)
changed: [192.168.0.250] => (item=screenfetch)
ok: [192.168.0.250] => (item=echo)
```

I don't know if it is because of the duplicate values or because the line already exists in the file.

Is there a way of forcing the module to add all of the items?

Comment: According the information provided, the third line is not "skipped" but already exists, therefore the message "ok".

Comment: Ok so my question is : is it possible to force adding it ?

Comment: `lineinfile` looks for a line. if it exists aleady it does not add it. This looks like a wrong tooling inside an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info). My guess is that you actually need [`blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html) or probably even better a [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html). But we can't be sure without more info on your exact use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun question. The answer is precisly as Zeitounator describes in the comment section. However, you can workaround your problem by e.g:

```yaml
- name: "Test..."
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    dest: /root/one
    line: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - echo
    - 'echo '
```

Bash doesn't care about whitespacing, so it will simply execute the command without issues.

Comment: Thanks that will do the trick.  But I also tried with blockinfile like Zeitounator suggested me.  I think it is more clean :-)